# What is the reason of different running times on a deterministic code with the same dataset on GPU?

Tags: time, gpu, gpgpu

I am running a piece of code on Nvidia tesla k40c GPU and measuring the running time of the code. The code is deterministic and I am using the same dataset in each run, but the time I get is different in each run. for example, about 60% of times, it is around 1.7 seconds, 10% of times it is around 2.5 seconds and 30% of times it is around 3.5 seconds.
I am wondering what causes this difference in different runs? is it related to processes on GPU? and should I take the average of this numbers as running time?

Comment: Have you ruled out things like transferring over the data and warming up the caches during the first run, other processes running jobs on the GPU at the same time and power management?

Comment: @Quinchilion , No I didn't, I don't know how to warm up cashes during the first run, how can I do that?

Comment: To profile it properly, make sure no other process is using the GPU at the moment and then run your code several times with the same data right after each other, but discard the timing of the first run.